# TableView Image Load Problem.(Full Code fot the tableCell)

Tags: ios4

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  dictionary = [QuestionMutableArray objectAtIndex:0];

  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"BeginingCell";

  BeginingCell *cell=(BeginingCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

  if (cell == nil) {

  ```
  NSArray *topLevelObjects=[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BeginingCell" owner:self options:nil ];

  for(id CurrentObject in topLevelObjects)
  {
      if ([CurrentObject isKindOfClass:[BeginingCell class]]) {

          cell=(BeginingCell *) CurrentObject;
          break;
      }
  }
  ```

  }

  // Configure the cell.

  if(indexPath.row==0)
  {

  ```
  cell.SectionTitle.text=[dictionary objectForKey:@"question"];
  cell.Option1.text=[dictionary objectForKey:@"option1"];
  cell.Option2.text=[dictionary objectForKey:@"option2"];
  cell.Option3.text=[dictionary objectForKey:@"option3"];
  cell.Option4.text=[dictionary objectForKey:@"option4"];


  UIImage *imgDef=[UIImage imageNamed:@"man_kirstie_alley.jpg"];
  [cell.myImageView setImage:imgDef];




  [MyTestArray release];

  [cell.button1 setTitle:@"A." forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [cell.button2 setTitle:@"B." forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [cell.button3 setTitle:@"C." forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [cell.button4 setTitle:@"D." forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  ```

  }

  return cell;

}

Comment: is this the complete code for "cellForRowAtIndexPath"? please post complete code in "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method

Comment: You need to provide more detail, are there any error messages? What line of the code is throwing the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you must create a cell first. You could use a default cell like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

//---try to get a reusable cell---

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
    dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

//---create new cell if no reusable cell is available---
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
             reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

//---You would set the image here---
UIImage *imgDef=[UIImage imageNamed:@"man_kirstie_alley.jpg"];
cell.image = imgDef;

return cell;
```

Comment: Yes i am doing the same.I didn't post the whole code.But not working.It's crushing here :[cell.myImageView setImage:imgDef];

Comment: @sohel14-cse-ju: Then please post your error message from the console. To show the console in XCode select "Run>Console" from the menu

Comment: Here is the exception :*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[BeginingCell myImageView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4d2b0c0'

Comment: For All..It's working with this code...thanks to all for your response..:[[cell imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"man_kirstie_alley.jpg"]];

Comment: @sohel: I presume you subclasse UITableViewCell, is that right? Have you declared myImageView in your header or have you forgotten to synthesize the myImage property?